# Where are dynamic hyperlinks stored?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, shapefile, hyperlink

A while back (ArcGIS 10.0 times, or maybe even 9.3) a colleague of mine created a mxd with a few hundred manholes and attached [dynamic hyperlinks](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000004000000) to them (pointing to photos of them). (I know this might not be the most efficient method, but done is done.)

However, now we can't seem to find this shapefile/mxd, and I would really need a way to search for a shapefile that has such hyperlinks.

In the ArcGIS Help (linked above) it states that: *This [hyperlink] association is stored with your layer. They are also stored with your layer if you save the layer to a file. /.../ ArcMap uses the feature ID (FID) field to associate dynamic hyperlinks with features*.

This far in my research I've been unable to find a way to see where they are stored or how to convert the dynamic hyperlinks into a field based hyperlink (which could indicate how to access the hyperlinks). I can probably figure out a couple of strings that should be in a list like that, if it could be of any use.

Is there a way to search for shapefiles which contains dynamic hyperlinks? Preferably without heaps of programming, but I'm open to suggestions!

Comment: Do you know the name of the shapefile or mxd? You could write a python script to crawl through your directories

Comment: I do not know the name of the shapefile - that is what I want to find out (provided that the hyperlinks are stored within the shapefile itself). So yes, I could search through all directories, but searching for what? How can I filter out those shapefiles that contains hyperlinks?

Comment: It sounds like the "dynamic" hyperlinks are stored in the layer's properties. Layers are persisted inside the map document (MXD) itself, or .lyr files. A shapefile itself will not store these dynamic hyperlinks. I do not know how to convert the dynamic links to a static field though. You should ask your coworker for the MXD or layer files.

Comment: @blah238 Yeah, that's what I figured as well. Is there any way to access them other than one on one? I'm gonna need to update the links, would be nice to do that in python loop or similar and not manually...